# Optimal Jelly string compressor in Rust

Tags: rust, compression, bigint

I'm writing some small programs to practice Rust, and this one's a string compressor for the golfing language [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage) ([unofficial spec](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221428/decompress-an-integer-jelly-style)). It involves some non-ASCII stuff and bigints (from the `num-bigint` crate).

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use num_bigint::{BigUint, ToBigUint};
use num_traits::cast::ToPrimitive;
use std::fs;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn low_first(word: &str) -> String {
    let mut word_chars = word.chars();
    
    let first = word_chars.next().unwrap();
    
    first.to_lowercase().to_string() + &word_chars.collect::<String>()
}

enum MightContain {
    Contains(usize),
    ContainsCaps(usize),
    Missing
}

fn dict_contains(word: &String, dict: &Vec<&str>) -> MightContain {
    let low_word = word.to_lowercase();
    let low_first_word = low_first(word);
    
    let mut low: usize = 0;
    let mut high: usize = dict.len();

    while high > low {
        let mid = (low + high) / 2;

        let d_word = dict[mid];
        let low_d_word = d_word.to_lowercase();

        if low_d_word < low_word {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if low_d_word > low_word {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            if word == d_word {
                return MightContain::Contains(mid);
            } else if low_first_word == low_first(d_word) {
                return MightContain::ContainsCaps(mid);
            } else {
                return MightContain::Missing;
            }
        }
    }

    MightContain::Missing
}

fn calc_index(s: usize, ds: usize, p: usize, q: usize) -> usize {
    usize::try_from(
        isize::try_from(ds - s).unwrap() -
        isize::try_from((((s - 1) - p) * (((s - 1) - p) + 1)) / 2).unwrap() -
        isize::try_from(p).unwrap() +
        isize::try_from(q).unwrap() - 2
    ).unwrap()
}

fn char_diagram(word: &String) -> String {
    let mut diagram = String::from("(");
    
    for char in word.chars() {
        diagram.push(char);
        diagram.push_str(")(");
    }
    
    diagram.pop();
    
    diagram
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ModPair {
    add: BigUint,
    scale: BigUint
}

fn char_coding(word: &String) -> ModPair {
    let mut add = 0u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
    let mut scale = 1u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
    
    for char in word.chars().rev() {
        add = (add * 96u32.to_biguint().unwrap() + (if char == '\n' { 95 } else { (char as u32) - 32 }).to_biguint().unwrap()) * 3u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        scale *= (96 * 3).to_biguint().unwrap();
    }
    
    return ModPair {
        add: add,
        scale: scale
    };
}

fn dict_coding(short_dict: bool, caps: bool, wrong_sp: bool, index: usize) -> ModPair {
    let mut add = index.to_biguint().unwrap();
    let mut scale = (if short_dict { 20453u32 } else { 227845u32 }).to_biguint().unwrap();
    
    add = add * 2u32.to_biguint().unwrap() + (if short_dict { 1u32 } else { 0u32 }).to_biguint().unwrap();
    scale *= 2u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
    
    if caps || wrong_sp {
        add = (add * 3u32.to_biguint().unwrap() + (if wrong_sp { if caps { 2u32 } else { 1u32 } } else { 0u32 }).to_biguint().unwrap()) * 3u32.to_biguint().unwrap() + 2u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        scale *= 9u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
    } else {
        add = add * 3u32.to_biguint().unwrap() + 1u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        scale *= 3u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
    }
    
    return ModPair {
        add: add,
        scale: scale
    };
}

fn missing_coding(first: &ModPair, second: &ModPair) -> ModPair {
    ModPair {
        add: &second.add * &first.scale + &first.add,
        scale: &first.scale * &second.scale
    }
}

fn main() {
    print!("ASCII: ");
    
    let mut input_string = String::new();
    
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string).unwrap();
    
    print!("\n");
    
    input_string.pop();
    
    let mut string = String::new();
    
    for char in input_string.chars() {
        if char == '¶' {
            string.push('\n');
            
            continue;
        }
        
        if char < ' ' || char > '~' {
            eprintln!("Contains non-ASCII");
            
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
        
        string.push(char);
    }
    
    let raw_short_dict = fs::read_to_string("short.dict").expect("Could not read short.dict");
    let raw_long_dict = fs::read_to_string("long.dict").expect("Could not read long.dict");
    
    let short_dict: Vec<&str> = raw_short_dict.split("\n").collect();
    let long_dict: Vec<&str> = raw_long_dict.split("\n").collect();
    
    let string_length = string.chars().count();
    let tri_string_length = string_length * (string_length + 1) / 2;
    
    if string_length == 0 {
        println!("Optimal cost: {} bits", 0.0);
        println!("Diagram: {}", "");
        
        return;
    }
    
    if string_length == 1 {
        println!("Optimal cost: {} bits", f64::round(f64::log2(3.0 * 96.0) * 100.0) / 100.0);
        println!("Diagram: {}", string);
        
        return;
    }
    
    let mut optimal_costs: Vec<f64> = vec![0.0; tri_string_length - string_length];
    let mut diagrams: Vec<String> = vec!["".to_string(); tri_string_length - string_length];
    let mut codings: Vec<ModPair> = vec![ModPair {
        add: 0u32.to_biguint().unwrap(),
        scale: 0u32.to_biguint().unwrap()
    }; tri_string_length - string_length];
    
    for i in 2..(string_length + 1) {
        for k in 0..(string_length - (i - 1)) {
            let word = string.chars().skip(k).take(i).collect::<String>();
            
            let no_sp_word;
            
            if word.chars().next().unwrap() == ' ' {
                no_sp_word = word[1..].to_string();
            } else {
                no_sp_word = word[..].to_string();
            }
            
            let mut cost = f64::log2(3.0 * 96.0) * (i as f64);
            let mut diagram = char_diagram(&word);
            let mut coding = char_coding(&word);
            
            let contains = if i < 60 { dict_contains(&no_sp_word, if no_sp_word.len() <= 5 { &short_dict } else { &long_dict }) } else { MightContain::Missing };
            
            match contains {
                MightContain::Contains(dict_index) => {
                    let word_cost = f64::log2(3.0 * 2.0 * (if (word.chars().next().unwrap() == ' ') == (k == 0) { 3.0 } else { 1.0 }) * (if no_sp_word.len() <= 5 { 20453.0 } else { 227845.0 }));

                    if word_cost < cost {
                        cost = word_cost;
                        diagram = format!("({})", word);
                        coding = dict_coding(no_sp_word.len() <= 5, false, (word.chars().next().unwrap() == ' ') == (k == 0), dict_index);
                    }
                },
                MightContain::ContainsCaps(dict_index) => {
                    let word_cost = f64::log2(3.0 * 2.0 * 3.0 * (if no_sp_word.len() <= 5 { 20453.0 } else { 227845.0 }));

                    if word_cost < cost {
                        cost = word_cost;
                        diagram = format!("({})", word);
                        coding = dict_coding(no_sp_word.len() <= 5, true, (word.chars().next().unwrap() == ' ') == (k == 0), dict_index);
                    }
                },
                MightContain::Missing => {
                    if i >= 3 {
                        let first_index = calc_index(string_length, tri_string_length, k + 1, k + i);
                        let first_cost = f64::log2(3.0 * 96.0) + optimal_costs[first_index];

                        if first_cost < cost {
                            cost = first_cost;
                            diagram = format!("({}){}", word.chars().next().unwrap(), diagrams[first_index]);
                            coding = missing_coding(&char_coding(&String::from(word.chars().next().unwrap())), &codings[first_index]);
                        }

                        let second_index = calc_index(string_length, tri_string_length, k, (k + i) - 1);
                        let second_cost = optimal_costs[second_index] + f64::log2(3.0 * 96.0);

                        if second_cost < cost {
                            cost = second_cost;
                            diagram = format!("{}({})", diagrams[second_index], word.chars().last().unwrap());
                            coding = missing_coding(&codings[second_index], &char_coding(&String::from(word.chars().last().unwrap())));
                        }
                    }

                    if i >= 4 {
                        for split in 2..((i + 1) - 2) {
                            let first_index = calc_index(string_length, tri_string_length, k, k + split);
                            let second_index = calc_index(string_length, tri_string_length, k + split, k + i);

                            let split_cost = optimal_costs[first_index] + optimal_costs[second_index];

                            if split_cost < cost {
                                cost = split_cost;
                                diagram = format!("{}{}", diagrams[first_index], diagrams[second_index]);
                                coding = missing_coding(&codings[first_index], &codings[second_index]);
                            }

                            // cost = cmp::min_by(cost, , |x, y| x.partial_cmp(y).unwrap())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            let index = calc_index(string_length, tri_string_length, k, k + i);
            
            optimal_costs[index] = cost;
            diagrams[index] = diagram;
            codings[index] = coding;
        }
    }
    
    let string_index = calc_index(string_length, tri_string_length, 0, string_length);
    
    println!("Optimal cost: {} bits", f64::round(optimal_costs[string_index] * 100.0) / 100.0);
    println!("Diagram: {}", diagrams[string_index]);
    
    print!("\n");
    
    let code_page = concat!(
        "¡¢£¤¥¦©¬®µ½¿€ÆÇÐÑ×ØŒÞßæçðıȷñ÷øœþ !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¶",
        "°¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ƁƇƊƑƓƘⱮƝƤƬƲȤɓƈɗƒɠɦƙɱɲƥʠɼʂƭʋȥẠḄḌẸḤỊḲḶṂṆỌṚṢṬỤṾẈỴẒȦḂĊḊĖḞĠḢİĿṀṄȮṖṘṠṪẆẊẎŻạḅḍẹḥịḳḷṃṇọṛṣṭ§Äẉỵẓȧḃċḋėḟġḣŀṁṅȯṗṙṡṫẇẋẏż"
    );
    
    let mut final_string = String::new();
    
    let mut n = codings[string_index].add.clone();
    
    while n != 0u32.to_biguint().unwrap() {
        let mut digit = &n % 250u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        
        if digit == 0u32.to_biguint().unwrap() {
            digit = 250u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        }
        
        n = (&n - &digit) / 250u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        
        digit -= 1u32.to_biguint().unwrap();
        
        final_string.push(code_page.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[digit.to_usize().unwrap()]);
    }
    
    println!("String: {}", final_string.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
}
```

It reads a dictionary of words from files called `short.dict` and `long.dict` (you can find those [here](https://gist.github.com/Radvylf/090c800cd061878aaab39b7b837798a6) if you want to run it yourself), and its dependencies are `num-bigint` 0.4.3 and `num-traits` 0.2.11. When you run it, you just type some text, and it'll show you how it's grouped into words and what the resulting compressed output is. I think it's approximately `O(n³)`, but it's reasonably fast for inputs up to around a half kilobyte.

I'm pretty new to Rust so feedback on any parts of it would be helpful, but in particular:

- Is there a better way to initialize the vector `codings`? Currently I fill it with useless `ModPair`s which get overwritten later, which feels like a waste of time and memory, but using `Vec::with_capacity(...)` would cause errors when I tried to use the vector (since the capacity was right but the length was `0`)
- Is there a better way to do math with signed and unsigned number types in things like the `calc_index` function? I have to do a ton of `try_from`s and `unwrap`s, since subtracting the `usize`s sometimes would result in negative numbers in an in-between step (but the result is always positive, so I have to `try_from` and `unwrap` to a `usize` again)
- Is there a more elegant way to do math with bigints? For every constant I add or multiply to a bigint, I have to do something like `3u32.to_biguint().unwrap()`, which is really clumsy and verbose

Thanks!

Comment: The input string is ASCII-only, right?

Comment: @L.F. Yes. It should print something like `Contains non-ASCII` otherwise, though I didn't test that.

Answer (score 1):

## Q & A

> Is there a better way to initialize the vector `codings`? Currently I fill it with useless `ModPairs` which get overwritten later, which feels like a waste of time and memory, but using `Vec::with_capacity(...)` would cause errors when I tried to use the vector (since the capacity was right but the length was `0`)

```rust
let codings = Vec::with_capacity(/* ... */);

for i in /* ... */ {
    // instead of `codings[i] = /* ... */`
    codings.push(/* ... */);
}
```

> Is there a better way to do math with signed and unsigned number types in things like the `calc_index` function? I have to do a ton of `try_from`s and `unwrap`s, since subtracting the `usize`s sometimes would result in negative numbers in an in-between step (but the result is always positive, so I have to `try_from` and `unwrap` to a `usize` again)

Take `calc_index` for example.
The formula is a bit beyond my understanding,
but I think you can avoid negative values
by rearranging the terms
such that addition happens before subtraction
(if overflow isn't an issue):

```rust
fn calc_index(s: usize, ds: usize, p: usize, q: usize) -> usize {
    q + ds - s - ((((s - 1) - p) * (((s - 1) - p) + 1)) / 2) - p - 2
}
```

> Is there a more elegant way to do math with bigints? For every constant I add or multiply to a bigint, I have to do something like `3u32.to_biguint().unwrap()`, which is really clumsy and verbose

Operations such as `BigUint * u32` are supported.
See the section on `char_coding`.

## Formatting

Running `rustfmt` (via `cargo fmt`) formats the code
according to the official [Rust Style Guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/tree/master/style-guide).

Personally, I like to merge `use` declarations:

```rust
use {
    num_bigint::{BigUint, ToBigUint},
    num_traits::cast::ToPrimitive,
    std::{
        convert::TryFrom,
        fs,
        io::{self, Write},
    },
};
```

## Clippy

`cargo clippy` gives the following suggestions:

- `print!("\n")` becomes `println!()`,
  and `println!("Diagram: {}", "")` is just `println!("Diagram: ")`.
- `else { if .. }` can be collapsed into `else if ..`.
- `ModPair { add: add, scale: scale }` can be replaced with
  the [shorthand](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_field_names) `ModPair { add, scale }`.
- Functions should generally take `&str` instead of `&String`.
  See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a `String` (`&String`), `Vec` (`&Vec`), or `Box` (`&Box`) as a function argument?]
- Explicit `return` is [unnecessary](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_return) at the end of a block.
- Clippy suggests rewriting `char < ' ' || char > '~'` as
  `!(' '..='~').contains(&char)`.
- `.split("\n")` can be `.split('\n')`.
- `word.chars().next().unwrap() == ' '` can be simplified to
  `word.starts_with(' ')`
  (except the latter does not panic if `word.is_empty()`).

## `low_first`

> ```rust
> fn low_first(word: &str) -> String {
>     let mut word_chars = word.chars();
>
>     let first = word_chars.next().unwrap();
>
>     first.to_lowercase().to_string() + &word_chars.collect::<String>()
> }
> ```

`collect` allocates a `String`,
which is appended to another `String`;
quite wasteful (in theory, at least).
In fact, `Chars` (the type of `word.chars()`)
provide a method [`as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) that exposes its `&str` representation:

```
first.to_lowercase().to_string() + word_chars.as_str()
```

## `dict_contains`

Take `word: &str, dict: &[&str]` as arguments instead.

We can use [`binary_search_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) to simplify the function:

```rust
fn dict_contains(word: &str, dict: &[&str]) -> MightContain {
    let low_word = word.to_ascii_lowercase();
    let low_first_word = low_first(word);

    let pos = match dict.binary_search_by_key(&low_word, |s| s.to_ascii_lowercase()) {
        Ok(pos) => pos,
        Err(_) => return MightContain::Missing,
    };
    let d_word = dict[pos];

    if word == d_word {
        MightContain::Contains(pos)
    } else if low_first_word == low_first(d_word) {
        MightContain::ContainsCaps(pos)
    } else {
        MightContain::Missing
    }
}
```

Note that `to_ascii_lowercase` is better than `to_lowercase`
if the string is known to be ASCII-only.

## `char_diagram`

More intuitively:

```rust
fn char_diagram(word: &String) -> String {
    word.chars().flat_map(|c| ['(', c, ')']).collect()
}
```

## `char_coding`

`96u32.to_biguint().unwrap()`
can be simplified to `BigUint::from(96_u32)`.
Eliminating these magic constants helps clarify their meanings.
Also, I find `*=` and `+=` more readable here:

```rust
fn char_coding(word: &String) -> ModPair {
    use num_traits::{One, Zero};

    let mut add = BigUint::zero();
    let mut scale = BigUint::one();

    // better names welcome
    const ASCII_OFFSET: u32 = 32;
    const CHAR_RADIX: u32 = 96;
    const CODE_RADIX: u32 = 3;

    for c in word.chars().rev() {
        add *= CHAR_RADIX;
        add += match c {
            '\n' => CHAR_RADIX - 1,
            _ => c as u32 - ASCII_OFFSET,
        };
        add *= CODE_RADIX;

        scale *= CHAR_RADIX * CODE_RADIX;
    }

    ModPair { add, scale }
}
```

Note that `BigUint` supports built-in unsigned integer types
on the right-hand side of arithmetic operators.
I also renamed `char` to `c` since `char` is a built-in type name.

Similar comments apply to `dict_coding`.

## Printing

> ```rust
> print!("ASCII: ");
> // ...
> io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
> // ...
> print!("\n");
> ```

I recommended printing the prompt to `stderr`,
which not only eliminates the need to manually flush
but also allows the user to separate actual output from prompts
by separating `stdout` and `stderr`:

```rust
eprint!("ASCII: ");
```

## Pre-processing input

> ```rust
> let mut string = String::new();
>
> for char in input_string.chars() {
>     if char == '¶' {
>         string.push('\n');
>
>         continue;
>     }
>
>     if char < ' ' || char > '~' {
>         eprintln!("Contains non-ASCII");
>
>         std::process::exit(1);
>     }
>
>     string.push(char);
> }
> ```

How about

```rust
let string = input_string.replace('¶', "\n");
if string.chars().any(|c| !(' '..='~').contains(&c)) {
    eprintln!("Contains non-ASCII");
    std::process::exit(1);
}
```

## Other parts of `main`

`main` is a very long function.

It would be more convenient if the paths to the dictionaries
are provided as arguments.

`2..(string_length + 1)` is `2..=string_length`.

`string.chars().skip(k).take(i).collect::<String>`
is `string[k..(k + i)].to_owned()`
since `string` is ASCII-only.

Instead of

> ```rust
> let no_sp_word;
>
> if word.chars().next().unwrap() == ' ' {
>     no_sp_word = word[1..].to_string();
> } else {
>     no_sp_word = word[..].to_string();
> }
> ```

we have

```rust
let no_sp_word = if word.starts_with(' ') {
    &word[1..]
} else {
    &word[..]
};
```

(note that allocation is unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of helpful information here! I don't think the suggestion of `push`ing to `codings` would work since I don't insert items in order, but maybe I could `push` to a second `Vec`, and use a `Vec<usize>` to map between the indices.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Oops - didn't notice that the insertions are out of order.  In that case, I would stick with the current version, since initializing with all zero values is probably going to compile to a simple `memset` and unlikely to cause much overhead anyway.  If the elements are sparse enough, switching to another data structure (such as `HashMap`) might also be an option.